# logback create a new log instance programmatically

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am having a small query with LogBack in Java and i'm hoping someone on the forum might have the solution for me.

I am running some tests, I can run those tests in singles or multiples. When I am running them in multiples is where I get the issue. I want to log file to change depending on the name of the test case. For example when I run 10 tests and test 1 id 1, when that finishes and test 2 starts I want that to be reflected to the log file and I want a second log file to be created with id 2.

I hope that makes sense, and if you have any additional questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Logback's [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/sift/SiftingAppender.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="SIFTER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>testName</key>
            <defaultValue>UNKNOWN</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${testName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>test-${testName}.log</file>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>...</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFTER" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The value of `testName` will be substituted into the log file name. You set `testName` via `org.slf4j.MDC`. For example;

```
String testName = "...";
MDC.put("testName", testName);

// run your test
// ...

// remove the test name from MDC ready for the next test to set its own name
MDC.remove("testName");
```

You could use JUnit4's [TestName Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules#testname-rule) to get the current test name and then put/remove in `@Before`, `@After` methods.

Comment: Hey Glitch, thank you for the comment, let me try this to my code base and see how it behaves and I will return to you asap. Regards,

Comment: Hey Glitch, that was perfect man, thank you. I wasn't aware of the SiftingAppender, but now i have it sorted. Thank you again